# How to resolve "Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65"?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, ios, mobile-automation

**Environment:**

- iOS version : 10.2.1
- Mac iOS Version : 10.12 [macOS Sierra]
- Appium : 1.1.0-beta.2

**Question:**

Background : I am trying to automate iOS app. I followed process to setup required for iOS Automation. As major changes is continuously deployed from TeamAppium. Need help for below error:

> Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65

Any one resolved this? If anyone is also facing same issue, please add your findings in comments.